# Rails - No route matches POST

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, routes

I have the following in my routes.rb file:

`post 'report/mnps/generate' => 'report#mnps_generate', as: 'report_mnps_generate'`

Then, in my `reports/mnps.html.erb` view I have this:

`<%= button_to report_mnps_generate_path %>`

However, this button redirects to a post method at `reports/mnps`. Why is this button redirecting there instead of `report/mnps/generate`?

## EDIT

`rake routes` returns:

```
          Prefix Verb URI Pattern                             Controller#Action
              root GET  /                                       home#index
      report_index GET  /report(.:format)                       report#index
       report_mnps GET  /report/mnps(.:format)                  report#mnps
report_mnps_generate POST /report/mnps/generate(.:format)         report#mnps_generate
```

Comment: Should the controller action be `reports#mnps_generate`, i.e. `reports` in place of `report`, in your route definition?

Comment: Can you post the output of `rake routes`?

Comment: Done. I know I could define a post method to report/mnps that would work, I just can't figure out why it's redirecting there instead of report/mnps/generate.

Comment: For what it's worth, the button label even says "report/mnps/generate" since I didn't supply a label to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of `button_to` states that the first parameter is its name, which is usually used as label. See here:

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/button_to

To get a link to the page, you need to write the button like this

```
button_to('Clickme!', report_mnps_generate_path)
```

The reason why it loaded the page you stated is that the button is actually on that very same page and is simply reloading it since no other destination was defined in your `button_to` call.